# why this api (featuresInImage) can not work in iOS10 :- (NSArray<CIFeature *> *)featuresInImage:(CIImage *)image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, cidetector

```
+ (NSString *)readQRCodeImage:(UIImage *)imagePicked {
CIImage *qrcodeImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imagePicked.CGImage];
CIContext *qrcodeContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

// detector
CIDetector *qrcodeDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:qrcodeContext options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];

// read features
NSArray *qrcodeFeatures = [qrcodeDetector featuresInImage:qrcodeImage];

//
NSString *qrcodeResultString = nil;
if (qrcodeFeatures && qrcodeFeatures.count > 0) {
    for (CIQRCodeFeature *qrcodeFeature in qrcodeFeatures) {
        if (qrcodeResultString && qrcodeResultString.length > 0) {
            break;
        }
        qrcodeResultString = qrcodeFeature.messageString;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",qrcodeResultString);

return qrcodeResultString;
```

}

I want to read the image features such as the picture in iOS10.
The code work normal in iOS8 and iOS9.

I would be very grateful with any helps.
[image]

Comment: What actually is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think they did a modification to the *CIFeautre* class. Now you need to convert it to the subclass *CIQRCodeFeature*.

How I did this in Swift:

```
let userFeatures = userDetector?.features(in: userImage!) as? [CIQRCodeFeature]
userDecode = (userFeatures?[0].messageString)!
```